# get details of sms sent through default Android SMS application

Tags: android

I am trying to get details of sms sent through default Android SMS application by my application running in background. Is it possible to get these details like destination number and message sent.
Any ideas,please suggest.

Comment: only way use [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) for listening Changes  in `content://sms/` or for `content://sms/inbox`